# objShell.Run indefinite memory growth

Tags: vbscript, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a VBS script that simply periodically runs a shortcut from my desktop.  After isolating every possible line in my code, I determined that each time this line is called:

```
objShell.Run "Some Path"
```

The memory usage of the process increases by about 5Mb.  I am curios as to why would this happen and if there is any remedy to this.

Thanks!

Comment: I would be surprised if memory growth weren't a function of the actual external command you're running.

Comment: So the shortcut I run opens other scripts but is it in any way tied to the "objShell.Run"? I don't think so because all the processes I call conclude and yet the memory consumption grows